# Regex for matching something preceded by chosen letters which is then replaced

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex expression to match and replace `Yo/yo` with `Йо/йо` or `ЬО/ьо` based on the rules below.

- Replace `Yo/yo` (capital, non-capital letter) with `Йо/йо` if it is in the beginning of the word or is preceded by the letter: `а`, `ъ`, `о`, `у`, `е`, `и`.
- If the condition above is not met, replace `Yo/yo` with `ЬО/ьо`.

I believe the following regex would work but there are two issues:

- how do I make it work for capital (Yo/Йо/Ьо) and non-capital (yo/йо/ьо)?
- if the conditions for `Йо/йо` are not met, how do I replace with `ЬО/ьо` instead?

```cs
(?<=а|ъ|о|у|е|и)йо
```

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=а|ъ|о|у|е|и)йо", " "); // ??
```

### Test cases

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("Асансyoр", "Асансьор")]
[InlineData("Актyoр", "Актьор")]
[InlineData("Шофyoр", "Шофьор")]
[InlineData("Пощалyoн", "Пощальон")]
[InlineData("Trenyor", "Треньор")]
[InlineData("Булyoн", "Бульон")]
[InlineData("Бокyoр", "Бокьор")]
[InlineData("Сервитyoр", "Сервитьор")]
[InlineData("Раyoн", "Район")]
[InlineData("Маyoнеза", "Майонеза")]
[InlineData("Маyoр", "Майор")]
[InlineData("Yoрдан", "Йордан")]
[InlineData("Yoвка", "Йовка")]
public void ShouldReturnReplacedWord_WhenGivenWord(string word, string expected)
```

Comment: Use the `Regex.Replace` callback that accepts a `MatchEvaluator`.

Comment: @Dai, that's a good idea but I need to figure out how it works. I found the following example `text = Regex.Replace(text, "ia($|' '|[^a-z])", m => TransliterationSpecificBulgarianRuleReplacement(m.Value, "ия"));` `private static string TransliterationSpecificBulgarianRuleReplacement(string stringOrg, string stringReplacement) { return stringOrg.Length != 2 ? string.Format("{0}{1}", stringReplacement, stringOrg[2]) : stringReplacement ?? ""; }`

Comment: Is `а` meant to be Latin `a` (`U+61`) or Cyrillic `а` (`U+430`)?

Comment: @Dai, Cyrillic `а` (`U+430`). All of them are cyrillic

Comment: How is `"Rayon"` supposed to be converted to `"Район"`? While you've defined how `"yo"` => `"йо"` you haven't defined how Latin `"Ra"` gets converted to `"Ра"` nor `"n"` to `"н"`.

Comment: @Dai, I just set it up on GitHub https://github.com/Hulkstance/test-usecase. You can use that to test with. Here are the other examples https://github.com/Hulkstance/test-usecase/blob/main/Transliterator.Core/Helper.cs#L90

Comment: Is `"Сервитyoр"` meant to be convereted to `"Сервитьор"` or `"Светлyo"`?

Comment: `Сервитyoр` is meant to be converted to `Сервитьор`. `Светлyo` -> `Светльо`.

Comment: @Dai, oh, I didn't really think about it. I guess that's an exception. Just remove it from the test cases.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, you can leave it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me with xUnit in LinqPad 7:

```cs
#load "xunit"

void Main()
{
    RunTests();  // Call RunTests() or press Alt+Shift+T to initiate testing.
}

static readonly Regex _yoRegex = new Regex( @"(?<pre>[\bayаъоуеи]?)(?<yo>[Yy]o)(?<post>\w+)?", RegexOptions.Compiled );

static String ReplaceYo( String input )
{
    if( _yoRegex.IsMatch( input ) )
    {
        String replaced = _yoRegex.Replace( input, YoMatchEvaluator );
        return replaced;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "Input did not match regex." );
//      return input;
    }
}

static String YoMatchEvaluator( Match match )
{
    String pre  = match.Groups["pre" ].Value;
    String yo   = match.Groups["yo"  ].Value;
    String post = match.Groups["post"].Value;
    
    Boolean isBeginningOfWord = ( pre.Length == 0 ) && ( match.Index == 0 );
    Boolean isPrecededByVowel = ( pre.Length == 1 ); // Note that `\b` will mean `pre.Length == 0`.
    Boolean isEndOfWord       = ( post.Length == 0 );
    
    if( isBeginningOfWord || isPrecededByVowel )
    {
        if( yo == "Yo" )
        {
            return pre + "Йо" + post;
        }
        else if( yo == "yo" )
        {
            return pre + "йо" + post;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unexpected \"Yo\" match: \"{0}\"".FmtInv( yo ) );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( yo == "Yo" )
        {
            return pre + "ЬО" + post;
        }
        else if( yo == "yo" )
        {
            return pre + "ьо" + post;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unexpected \"Yo\" match: \"{0}\"".FmtInv( yo ) );
        }
    }
}

static class MyExtensions
{
    public static String FmtInv( this String format, params Object?[]? args ) => String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args: args );
}

#region private::Tests

[Theory]
[InlineData(  1, "Асансyoр", "Асансьор")]
[InlineData(  2, "Актyoр", "Актьор")]
[InlineData(  3, "Шофyoр", "Шофьор")]
[InlineData(  4, "Пощалyoн", "Пощальон")]
//[InlineData( 5, "Trenyor", "Треньор")]
[InlineData(  5, "Trenyor", "Trenьоr")]
[InlineData(  6, "Булyoн", "Бульон")]
[InlineData(  7, "Бокyoр", "Бокьор")]
[InlineData(  8, "Сервитyoр", "Сервитьор")]
[InlineData(  9, "Раyoн", "Район")]
[InlineData( 10, "Маyoнеза", "Майонеза")]
[InlineData( 11, "Маyoр", "Майор")]
[InlineData( 12, "Yoрдан", "Йордан")]
[InlineData( 13, "Yoвка", "Йовка")]
[InlineData( 14, "Светлyo", "Светльо")]
public void ShouldReturnReplacedWord_WhenGivenWord( Int32 testCase, String word, String expected)
{
    String actual = ReplaceYo( word );
    Assert.Equal( expected: expected, actual: actual );
}

#endregion
```

Test results:

| Input | Expected | Actual | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `"Асансyoр"` | `"Асансьор"` | `"Асансьор"` | Pass |
| `"Актyoр"` | `"Актьор"` | `"Актьор"` | Pass |
| `"Шофyoр"` | `"Шофьор"` | `"Шофьор"` | Pass |
| `"Пощалyoн"` | `"Пощальон"` | `"Пощальон"` | Pass |
| `"Trenyor"` | `"Trenьоr"` | `"Trenьоr"` | Pass |
| `"Булyoн"` | `"Бульон"` | `"Бульон"` | Pass |
| `"Бокyoр"` | `"Бокьор"` | `"Бокьор"` | Pass |
| `"Сервитyoр"` | `"Сервитьор"` | `"Сервитьор"` | Pass |
| `"Раyoн"` | `"Район"` | `"Район"` | Pass |
| `"Маyoнеза"` | `"Майонеза"` | `"Майонеза"` | Pass |
| `"Маyoр"` | `"Майор"` | `"Майор"` | Pass |
| `"Yoрдан"` | `"Йордан"` | `"Йордан"` | Pass |
| `"Yoвка"` | `"Йовка"` | `"Йовка"` | Pass |
| `"Светлyo"` | `"Светльо"` | `"Светльо"` | Pass |

Comment: Thank you! I'm testing it right now. Shouldn't `[\bayаъоуеи]` be just `[\bаъоуеи]`?

Comment: @nop It needs to match both Latin `a` and Cyrillic `а` which are separate character values. Ditto for `y` and some other values.

Comment: btw what is `FmtInv`?

Comment: @nop Oh, sorry - it's this: `public static String FmtInv( this String format, params Object?[]? args ) => String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args: args );`